# squaring a 150 million digit number in Java

Tags: java, math, nullpointerexception, biginteger

ok, so here is the deal. I have made a program that creates a byte array that has 150000000 different addresses. I then put that into a for loop that will assign the values a random positive number between 0-9 and it outputs that number to a file.
that all works but where i'm running into problems is where I actually try to square it. im using the class BigInteger to try to store the number im trying to square. this is my code to try to put the number into a BigInteger

```
for(int i = 0; i<150000000; i++)
    {
        square = square.add(BigInteger.valueOf(number[i]));
    }
```

and my compiler at run time gives me the error: Exception in thread "main"     java.lang.NullPointerException
    at numberge.Numberge.main(Numberge.java:44)
Java Result: 1

I have also tried to make the for loop iterate a smaller amount of times and it does not help. any ideas?

the entire output that the program gives me is:
run:
done generating/now writing to file
squaring
150000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at numberge.Numberge.main(Numberge.java:43)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9 seconds)

the entire code is

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Numbersqu {
static byte[] number = new byte[150000000];
static Random generator = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
static BigInteger square = null;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

    for(int i = 0; i<150000000; i++)
    {
        number[i] =   (byte) Math.abs(generator.nextInt(9));
    }
    System.out.println("done generating/now writing to file");
    File file = new File("number.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    for(int i = 0; i<150000000; i++)
    {
      bw.write(Integer.toString(number[i]));
    }
      bw.close();
      System.out.println("generating number to square");
      System.out.println(Integer.toString(number.length));
      for(int i = 0; i<150000000; i++)
    {
        square = square.add(BigInteger.valueOf(number[i]));
    }
     System.out.println("Writing square to file");
    File file2 = new File("square.txt");
    if (!file2.exists()) 
    {
            file2.createNewFile();
}
     FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(file2.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);
                     bw2.write(square.toString());
                     bw2.close();


    }
}
```

this is as far as I have gotten, once I can actually store the number then I will square it.

Comment: what is the length of number?

Comment: paste your code for someone to help

Comment: Looks like you probably need to initialize `square` before the loop

Comment: This is a funny way to calculate a square of a number....

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing the results. Currently any answer is likely to just be guessing.

Comment: I did need to initialize square. thank you, it's 150 million digits long so when generating a random number i didn't want to pass the largest 150 million digit number as a parameter. that's why I did it this way.

Comment: Also, you just adding numbers to BigInteger, instead of adding digits, use `square = square.mul(10).add(number[i])` and change `for (int i=150..-1; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: Please post the entire exception (error) message with trace back.

Comment: When you fix the NullPointerException, you're probably gonna be asking another question: Why does it take forever to square a 150 million digit number? Answer: Java uses an `O(N^2)` multiplication algorithm. With `N = 150,000,000`, that's not gonna finish for a while.  :)

Comment: Why are you using BigInteger at all? A `long` would be much faster and simpler.

Comment: can a long hold a variable that is 150 million digits long?

Answer (score 1):

So here it is. Your variable square is null.

```
static BigInteger square = null;
```

Initialize it to some value before using here :

```
for(int i = 0; i<150000000; i++)
    {
        square = square.add(BigInteger.valueOf(number[i]));
    }
```

Comment: ok, i did that but i have run into another issue. when i do that no matter what number i make it when i initialize it it always ends being only 9 digits long. and i made it output square.bitCount() and it's always 13 or 14.

Comment: did you initialize with value zero or something else?

Comment: first I tried 0, then i did like 90000000 then, 4, then 23 with the same results

Comment: keep it zero as you are adding to it later. Now regarding the other issue, you are getting the output as per your logic. You populate this with similar values everytime and hence get similar result - number[i] =   (byte) Math.abs(generator.nextInt(9));

Comment: I use the line: square = square.add(BigInteger.valueOf(number[i]));     to add each element of number[] to square. I would think that this would work? do you know what can be done to make it work

Comment: Well, its difficult for me to comment on that. Your logic doesn't essentially compute a square

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible issues, but with this code snippet, not enough information is presented to really know either of these items are the true problem.

1. Perhaps square is not initalized.  If so, the

   square = square.add(...

will dereference a null pointer at the `square.add(...)` call, causing a null pointer exception.

To fix such an item
    square = new Square(); 
should be called beforehand.

1. Perhaps `number` is not initialized.

fixing it is the same as fixing `square`.

1. Perhaps `number[i]` lacks a value.  This happens quite often when dealing with arrays of objects.

Comment: I just posted my entire source. I have tried changing my for loop to only go through 10 times and it will still give me the same error. I use the number array up to value 150000000 in other for loops. and I initialized square as null, that's where I believe I may have a problem